# Accessing the created element

Tags: javascript

```
response.data = <div id="login">Hi</div>
```

How to refer to the newly created element, let's say I inserted html code, a div appeared at the bottom of the page and I need to refer to it?

```
   document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', response.data)

   thisModal = document.getElementById('login')
```

Comment: That first assignment is not valid (vanilla) JavaScript. But the general approach in your second snippet works fine. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/szphaogq/)

Comment: As @trincot mentioned, the first line is not valid. If you want to refer to a div in your javascript code, your last line is doing that.

Comment: You can use [document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) to create the element, which return a reference to the created element, such that you have the reference in the first place, then use [`document.body.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) to insert the element. Or you can just do what you did, query for the element after you insert it as html.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.